# Validar Modal Boostrap con envío Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo una aplicación `ASP.NET MVC` y tengo un modal en donde hago el envío de datos por `AJAX`, pero quiero validar los campos con `jQuery Validate` y que si no es el tipo correcto de dato le muestre un mensaje.

He tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente manera pero no me funciona.

```js
$("#btnSave").click(function() {

  $("#newModalForm").validate({
    rules: {
      Description: {
        required: true,
      },
      Discount: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 1
      }
    },
    messages: {
      Description: {
        required: "Fiel Required",
      },
      Discount: {
        required: "Fiel Required",
        minlength: "value must be that 0"
      }
    },

    debug: true,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var Description = $("#Description").val();
      var Discount = $("#Discount").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Datos")',
        data: {
          Description: Description,
          Discount: Discount
        },
        dataType: "json",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
          //remuevo modal
          $("#close_btn").trigger("click");
          $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Error while inserting data");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title w-100 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Create e</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group col-12">
            <input class="form-control small col-12" type="text" name="Description" id="Description" placeholder="Description" require />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-12">
            <input class="form-control small col-12" type="number" name="Discount" id="Discount" placeholder="Surchage" min="1" require />
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="close_btn" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i> Close
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btnSave">
                <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Podrían indicarme en qué estoy fallando?

El envío de `AJAX` me funciona si no aplico las validaciones de `jQuery Validate`, pero si las aplico el formulario no me envía los datos, ni tampoco me valida los campos.

Comment: Prueba a **quitarle** de tu función JavaScript el **debug: true**. En esta pregunta lo puedes ver mejor explicado: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404371/jquery-validate-debug-mode-not-showing-any-output-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404371/jquery-validate-debug-mode-not-showing-any-output-in-chrome)

Comment: sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Aunque no creo que sea el problema, en los "inputs" tienes un atributo "require" .. es "required". Modifícalo a ver que pasa...

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es lo que te recomendó @RafaelAcosta: elimina el parámetro `debug`. Si vas a [la documentación](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), podrás leer para qué se utiliza este parámetro:

> **debug:** Enables debug mode. If true, the form is not submitted and certain errors are displayed on the console (will check if a window.console property exists). Try to enable when a form is just submitted instead of validation stopping the submit.
>
> *Traducción: **debug**: Habilita el modo debug. Si es true, el formulario no es enviado y algunos errores son mostrados en la consola (se chequeará si la propiedad window.console existe). Intenta habilitarlo cuando un formulario es enviado en vez de que la validación detenga el envío.*

Lo segundo es que no sitúes el código de validación dentro del evento `click` del botón del formulario. El plugin se encargará de capturar el evento `submit` del formulario y ejecutar el método `submitHandler` cuando ocurra.

Lo tercero es que cambies el botón `Save` de tipo `button` a tipo `submit`, de esta manera el hacer click sobre él, el formulario intentará ser enviado y este evento será capturado por el plugin.

Aquí te dejo tu mismo snippet eliminando algún código de más que no era necesario para el ejemplo y situando como `URL` una de tipo post the [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/):

```js
$("#newModalForm").validate({
  rules: {    
    Description: {
      required: true,
    },
    Discount: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      minlength: 1
    }
  },
  messages: {
    Description: {
      required: "Fiel Required",
    },
    Discount: {
      required: "Fiel Required",
      minlength: "value must be that 0"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    var Description = $("#Description").val();
    var Discount = $("#Discount").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      data: {
        Description: Description,
        Discount: Discount
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error while inserting data");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="newModalForm">
  <div class="form-group col-12">
    <input class="form-control small col-12" type="text" name="Description" id="Description" placeholder="Description" require />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-12">
    <input class="form-control small col-12" type="number" name="Discount" id="Discount" placeholder="Surchage" min="1" require />
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="close_btn" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
        <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i> Close
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btnSave">
        <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```